# iOS internal mic to AirPlay (streaming)

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio

There are plenty of examples (incl. source) of apps out there that a) Record audio (from the internal mic of an iOS device), and b) Play audio (over AirPlay)

I'm having trouble finding any sort of example/documentation that might demonstrate how to do both of these simultaneously (or, within expected network latency).  I'm interested in routing audio, in real time, from the internal mic of an iOS device to an AirPlay device (Airport Express, Apple TV, etc.).  No recording necessary.

Can anyone either describe one way this might be done, or point me in the direction of some related documentation?  Thank you!

Comment: Real real time is impossible.  There is inherent latency.  Do you have a very low latency requirement for this project?

Comment: Just to clarify: "Real-time" meaning direct streaming.  I realize there will always be some latency.

Comment: Any luck with solving this challenge?

Comment: Nope... never got a satisfactory result.